# How do I show custom error message on OnItemSaved event?

Tags: sitecore-api

The ask is to show the following kind of message on the OnItemSaved event.

[image]

I am unable to show a similar custom message on the OnItemSaved event. I am always getting some default exception message. I tried achieving it by throwing the custom exception as:

```
throw new CustomException("Section heading cannot have more than 20 characters !");
```

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom processor in the experience editor or/and content editor based on your requirement. A simple way to create a custom patch config to register the processor and a class file with your code.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
      <sitecore>
         <pipelines>
            <!--Disyplay warning in the content editor-->
             <getContentEditorWarnings>
                      <processor type="xyz.Warning.YourClass, xyz" />
             </getContentEditorWarnings>

            <!--Disyplay warning in the Exprience editor-->
             <getPageEditorNotifications>
                      <processor type="xyz.GetPageEditorNotifications.YourClass,xyz" />
             </getPageEditorNotifications>
         </pipelines>
      </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Your experience editor class will inherit the GetPageEditorNotificationsProcessor
here is some sample code for the expriecne editor-

```
namespace xyz.GetPageEditorNotifications
 {
    public class YourClass : GetPageEditorNotificationsProcessor
      {
        public override void Process(GetPageEditorNotificationsArgs arguments)
          {
             Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)arguments, "arguments");
             Item contextItem = arguments.ContextItem;
              // your code
          }
      }
  }
```

For Content editor, the code will look like this

```
namespace xyz.Warning
{
     public class YourClass
     {
        public void Process(GetContentEditorWarningsArgs args)
        {
            var item = args.Item;

            if (item == null)
                return;
            // Your Code

        }
    }
}
```

I guess this will help you.